# How can I read zip files from Google Storage in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip, google-cloud-storage

An application creates a zip file and stores it to Google Storage. I am working on the web server side which is responsible for grabbing the zip file extract the contents etc. The web service is written in Python App Engine. So far I have set the credentials and by following the tutorials I am able to list buckets contents. Although I am able to read the metadata and file information I am not able to get the contents to zip file module. Following [this](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary.html)
guide I have ended up in that spot which is not working:

```
uri = boto.storage_uri(BUCKET_NAME, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
objs = uri.get_bucket()
files = []
for obj in objs:
  object_contents = StringIO.StringIO()
  if obj.get_key():
    obj.get_file(object_contents)
    my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(object_contents)
    object_contents.close()
    files.append(my_zip)
print len(files)
```

I am getting: `BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`

How can I read the content properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now [an API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview.html) that lets you manipulate objects in Google Storage directly. Using that, you can get a file-like object for the zipfile, and simply pass that to the `zipfile` module.